# XML Embedded Resource not loading in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

The following is my entire code. What I'm trying to do is get a random line of an XML resource file read to a label on Button10_Click, but the program is not identifying any information from the embedded xml file, is the resource stream getting 'lost' somewhere?

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Security.Permissions

Public Class Form1

    Dim asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
    Dim var = asm.GetManifestResourceStream("WindowsApplication2.british-english-dictionary.xml")

    Private Sub Button10_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button10.Click

          Dim rand = New Random()
          Dim myXml = New XDocument()

          Dim lexemeList = myXml.Descendants("lexeme").ToList()
          Dim randomLexeme = lexemeList(rand.Next(0, lexemeList.Count - 1))

          Label1.Text = randomLexeme

    End Sub
End Class
```

Edit: Example of the XML file is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<root>
<lexeme><grapheme>A</grapheme>  <phoneme>'eI</phoneme></lexeme>
<lexeme><grapheme>A'asia</grapheme>  <phoneme>a'eIZi@</phoneme></lexeme>
<lexeme><grapheme>A's</grapheme>     <phoneme>'eIz</phoneme></lexeme>
<lexeme><grapheme>AOL</grapheme>     <phoneme>'eI0l</phoneme></lexeme>
<lexeme><grapheme>AOL's</grapheme>   <phoneme>'eI0lz</phoneme></lexeme>
<lexeme><grapheme>Aaberg</grapheme>  <phoneme>'A:b3:g</phoneme></lexeme>
<lexeme><grapheme>Aaberg's</grapheme>    <phoneme>'A:b3:gz</phoneme></lexeme>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call [XDocument.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838349.aspx) to load the manifest stream :

```
Dim myXml = XDocument.Load(var)
var.Close()
```

Comment: I've tried running it with that ammendment you suggest but unfortunately `Dim randomLexeme = lexemeList(rand.Next(0, lexemeList.Count - 1))` is still out of bounds, because lexemeList.Count=0, probably because the Xml hasn't loaded properly.

Comment: @Andy Did you check if the document is already loaded in myXaml? try changing the loading option  `myXml.Load(var, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace)`

Comment: I'm not sure how to check that it's loaded in myXaml; is there an easy way to check? Ammending `myXml.Load(var, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace)` still gives that error.

Comment: @Andy Check what this give you `myXml.Nodes.Count`. Also Make sure the casing is correct. it might be `Lexeme` and not `lexeme`

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, I tried that and it returns 0. I have no idea why it isn't loading the xml properly and I can't find any examples of loading an embedded xml file.

Comment: @Andy I think my updated answer would work. Don't delcare a new xDocument. just use this line `Dim myXml = XDocument.Load(var)`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24281/discussion-between-andy-and-abzy)